# How to include a formula as part of the criterion when using COUNTIF?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am looking to count how many values are higher than the average of the values listed.

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 10 |

> Total: 150 
>  Average: 30

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,">30")
         Answer: 2
```

**How could I replace the ">30" with a formula?**

I tried the following with no success:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,""">"&AVERAGE(A1:A5)&"""")

=COUNTIF(A1:A5,textjoin("",TRUE,""">",AVERAGE(A1:A5),"""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,">"&AVERAGE(A1:A5))
```

The `&` concatenates the AVERAGE formula with the operand (in this case, the greater-than symbol).